# Slider with two handles- Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, slider

Is is possible in silverlight to get a slider with two handles?
I want to set the max and min value with the same slider.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom control for that purpose.

Here a question on StackOverflow that addresses this issue in a Metro XAML control, but is shouldn't be too different in Silverlight.

[Range Slider in Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805526/range-slider-metro-style-app)